# select the name as selected in dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, while-loop

Query for select God from God table

```
$sth =$dbh->prepare("SELECT god_id,god_name_ml,god_name_en,image,info_ml,info_en,details_ml,
       details_en,rounds_ml,rounds_en,mantra_ml,mantra_en,display_order FROM god");
       $sth->execute();
```

Query for select deity from deity table.Here god_id is the foreign key from god table

```
   $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT deity_id,god_id,deity_name_ml,deity_name_en,info_ml,info_en,details_ml,
      details_en,mantra_ml,mantra_en,display_order FROM deity
      WHERE deity_id = :deity_id");
    $stmt->bindValue(':deity_id',$deity_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $temp_array=$result[0];
    $god_id=$temp_array['god_id'];
```

display code for displaying god in dropdown from god table

```
<?php while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $row['god_id'];?>">
         <?php echo $row['god_name_en']; ?>
       </option>
       <?php } ?>
       </option>
   </select>
```

what I need is, in dropdown list the given god_id in god table is present in deity table  make it as selected.
only I need is selected Id's are selected

Comment: you can create an array with god id from deity table. Inside while loop you can check whether god id exist or not. if it exist show selected.Instead of creating array, you can check it from databse directly,but I will not suggest that as if you have 1000 god this check will perform 1000 time, which will slow the process

Comment: @Ms.Nehal I checked but have some changes in my ciodeing.please see my updated question

Comment: @sherinks, please check my updated answer

Comment: Thank you.Its working now.. @Ms.Nehal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check both the id's are same or not, try this :

```
<?php while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
  <option <?php if($row['god_id'] == $god_id) { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> value="<?php echo $row['god_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['god_name_en']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @sherinks, glad to help you ! :) Feel free to up-vote/accept if it helped anyhow or you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
  <option <?php if($row['id'] == $stmt->god_id) { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> value="<?php echo $row['god_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['god_name_en']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
                                          </option>
                                        </select>
```

Comment: here I use your code and change instead of $row[id],$stmt['id'] are $row[god_id],$stmt['god_id'] and run but get an error like"cannot use object type of pdo statement as array" @Dhara Parmar

Answer (score 0):

As you write each option compare whether God_I'd from God table matches the god_ID of the current option. If it does append the text "selected" after the value.

So the selected option will look something like

```
<option value='1' selected>foo</option>
```